# how to put text to right of picture in html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up separate sections within the body that would show info in them like this

[image]

using `float: left;` doesn't help, it only messes up the page layout.

here's my html...

```css
#a,
#g {
  background-color: #6d6d6d;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  list-style: none;
}

#pic {
  margin: +5% 0 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div Id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <ul id="a">
      <li>
        <a href="img/appstore.jpg">
          <img src="img/appstore.jpg" alt="" width=180px id="pic">
          <p>info</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <ul id="g">
      <li>
        <a href="img/googleplay.jpg">
          <img src="img/googleplay.jpg" alt="" width=180px id="pic">
          <p>info</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: in the picture of page layout: blue, green, red outlined boxes are meant to be the sections or containers. the orange are the pictures and the grey lines are the text lines.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using the same name for multiple instances of the same id for your images? ID's are supposed to be unique, you're better of using a class if you're going to group. Check my solution out for your question:

```css
#a, #g {
    color: #bdc3c7;
    list-style: none;
}

.pic {
    margin:+5% 0 0;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float:left;
}

.sections {
  height:100px;
  background-color: #6d6d6d;
}

.info {
  margin:+5% 10px;
  float:left;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
   <div Id="wrapper">
      <section class="sections">
          <ul id="a">
            <li>
              <a href="img/appstore.jpg">
                <img src="img/appstore.jpg" alt="" width=180px class="pic">
                <p class="info">info</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>

        <section class="sections">
         <ul id="g">
            <li>
              <a href="img/googleplay.jpg">
                <img src="img/googleplay.jpg" alt="" width=180px class="pic">
                <p class="info">info</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>   
        </section>
    </div>
```

1. I classed the section tags as that's what you would need to add the background colour to and set a height. You would need to set a height as the items are floating so they would not stretch the section automatically, so you need to provide a fixed height.
2. I added classes to your paragraphs as these would also need to be floated left as well as your images. Also you needed to add the same margins as your images.
3. I changed your pics ID's to classes.

If you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

change id="pic" to class="pic". because ID should be used 1 time in a page..

then write in css:

```
.pic {
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `float:right`

```css
#wrapper ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#wrapper ul li {
    background-color: #6d6d6d;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper ul li img {
    float: left;
}

#wrapper ul li .details {float: right;width: 75%;}
```

```html
    <div Id="wrapper">
      <section>
          <ul id="a">
            <li>
              <a href="img/appstore.jpg">
                <img src="img/appstore.jpg" alt="" width=180px id="pic">
                <!-- Wrapped into div -->
                <div class="details">
                    <p>info</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/appstore.jpg">
                <img src="img/appstore.jpg" alt="" width=180px id="pic">
                <!-- Wrapped into div -->
                <div class="details">
                    <p>info</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/appstore.jpg">
                <img src="img/appstore.jpg" alt="" width=180px id="pic">
                <!-- Wrapped into div -->
                <div class="details">
                    <p>info</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/appstore.jpg">
                <img src="img/appstore.jpg" alt="" width=180px id="pic">
                <!-- Wrapped into div -->
                <div class="details">
                    <p>info</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/appstore.jpg">
                <img src="img/appstore.jpg" alt="" width=180px id="pic">
                <!-- Wrapped into div -->
                <div class="details">
                    <p>info</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code and list things a bit.. Tell me if i misinterpreted your question..

```html
        <html>
        <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
          <style>
                #a, #g {
                    background-color: #6d6d6d;
                    color: #bdc3c7;
                    list-style: none;
                    width: 100%;
                }
        
                #pic {
                    margin: +5% 0 0;
                    border: 3px solid black;
                    display:table-cell; width:100px;height:100px;
                }
        
                #wrapper {
                  max-width: 1200px;
                  margin: 0 auto;
                  padding: 0 5%;
                  list-style: none;
                }
                section{
                    width: 100%;
                }
        
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div Id="wrapper">
              <section>
                      <a href="img/appstore.jpg" id="a">
                        <div style="display:table" id="g">
                            <div style="" id="pic">
                                <img src="img/appstore.jpg" width=180px alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding:12 16;">
                                <p>info</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                      </a>
        
                </section>
        
                <section>
                    <a href="img/googleplay.jpg">
                        <div style="display:table" id="g">
                            <div style="" id="pic">
                                <img src="img/googleplay.jpg" alt="" width=180px>
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding:12 16;">
                                <p>info</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </a>
                </section>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```